# jQuery/JavaScript Library for avatar creation?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, avatar-generation

Is anyone aware of a JavaScript or jQuery library that enables the creation of Pixelart avatars?  I'm hoping for something with a Mr. Potatohead style face creation using components and resulting in a GIF.

If not, I guess I'll need to make one myself.

Comment: This will be tricky, because JavaScript doesn't really support writing files.  One option would be using a canvas, then rendering to a data URL with [toDataURL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl).  Both canvas and data URIs still have limited support, and this doesn't let you save a file directly.

Comment: Hey, did you gt any solution? If yes, do post about it so that it can help others.

Comment: Why was this closed? This is a valid question to me!

Comment: @kheya Questions asking for software libraries are typically off-topic because they tend to generate spam and non-answers. I'm a bit conflicted about answering it myself, but I think I managed to refrain from the usual pitfalls of these types of questions.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Blockies](https://github.com/download13/blockies).

Its usage is pretty simple (from the [README](https://github.com/download13/blockies#use)):

```
var icon = blockies.create({ // All options are optional
    seed: 'randstring', // seed used to generate icon data, default: random
    color: '#dfe', // to manually specify the icon color, default: random
    bgcolor: '#aaa', // choose a different background color, default: white
    size: 15, // width/height of the icon in blocks, default: 10
    scale: 3 // width/height of each block in pixels, default: 5
});
```

where `icon` is a canvas element.

You can't really plan what you're going to get, though: you just end up with a random icon unless you specify a seed to generate it from.

Comment: Looks impressive and simple solution.