# jQuery: Swap Classes based on Class position

Tags: jquery

I'm creating an Avatar designer, where users can customize things like hairstyles & hair colours from a preselection.

It is basically a form with radio buttons that can be used to customize the avatar.

My form is wrapped in a DIV that has three classes:

```
<div id="container" class="hair-blonde skin-pink boy">
```

I need the classes to take the values of the radio buttons. 
So if a user clicks on a hair colour, the value of the hair colour radio button will overwrite the `hair-blonde` class.

I can't use  [ToggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) or [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) because these don't give you control over which class is changed. Also, if hair-blonde changes to hair-red, then the script wont work anymore as it will still be looking for hair-blonde.

I thought I could use [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203966/jquery-get-the-first-class-only-from-a-element) to turn the list of classes into an array.
However, when I try to swap the classes nothing happens.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$(".skincolour input").click(function(){
var newskincolour = $(this).val();
var skin_colour = $('#container').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
var skin_colour = newskincolour;
});
```

I have also tried this as a variation:

```
$(".skincolour input").click(function(){
var newskincolour = $(this).val();
var skin_colour = $('#container').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
var skin_colour = $(".skincolour input").val();
});
```

Could someone give me some pointers as to what I am doing wrong?

- Here is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnrZ8/) of my work
- Here is [live site](http://olo.uk.com/files/test/test6/) of my work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach could work, but you forgot to overwrite the element's `class` attribute. Try this:

```
$(".skincolour input").click(function(){
    var newskincolour = $(this).val();
    var classes = $('#container').attr('class').split(' ');
    classes[1] = newskincolour;
    $('#container').attr('class', classes.join(' '));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to remove the classes of the same category, followed by `addClass`.

Comment: I don't understand. Lets say I tell Jquery to remove .hairblonde and add .hairred. Well, when the user clicks on a different colour, the script wont work as .hairblonde no longer exists.

Comment: You may remove classes that aren't present. So you may do `.removeClass('.hairblonde').removeClass('.hairbrown').addClass('.hairred');`

Comment: Thanks for your help. bfavaretto's solution is slightly better as less code writing is required. However, your is still a good idea! Thanks again!