# CSS - SASS: Using @each based mixins to generate multiple backgrounds

Tags: css, sass

I am using CSS to create a catalog of hairstyles and colours. I have a combination of 55 different colours and hair styles. Each hair style and colour has its own image SVG file and I need to combine them all into a single background (Using the multiple background feature of CSS3).

I have written this mixing to generate the multiple backgrounds: (It is based on the mixin [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645962/sass-using-two-each-lists-in-scss))

```
@mixin style-matrix($colors, $styles) {
    @each $s in $styles {
        @each $c in $colors {


                url("pps#{$s}#{$c}.svg"),
        }
    }
}



$colors: blonde, red, dkbrown, ltbrown, black;
$styles: hairboy1, hairboy2, hairboy3, hairboy4, hairboy5, hairgirl6, hairgirl1, hairgirl4, hairgirl2, hairgirl3, hairgirl5;

.hidden {
background: @include style-matrix($colors, $styles) url("base.svg);
}
```

(see [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AExig) here)

However, every time I run the mixin, I get this error message:

```
Invalid CSS after "...            url": expected "{", was "("pps#{$s}#{$c}..."
```

How can I use the mixin to generate the multiple backgrounds?

Comment: Can you show what you want the resulting CSS to look like?  It looks like you're trying to make all the possible hair/color combinations be a background image of your `.hidden` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixins return property/value pairs. If you want the value only, you need a function. It looks like this:

```
@function style-matrix($colors, $styles) {
  $bg: compact();
  @each $s in $styles {
    @each $c in $colors {
      $bg: join($bg, url("pps#{$s}#{$c}.svg"), comma);
    }
  }
  @return $bg;
}

.hidden {
  background: style-matrix($colors, $styles), url("base.svg");
}
```